# Creating collision diagram in Civil3D

Tags: autocad, diagram, civil3d

I've been trying to make a collision diagram similar to the one shown below in Civil3D.

[image: Collision Diagram]

I've added my collision data as COGO points with geolocation and applied some basic styles, but there are 2 main issues. Firstly, many of the collision points overlap (as shown below) causing the diagram to look cluttered and secondly, most of the points aren't oriented properly.
[image: Overlapping Collisions]

I'm curious if there's any way to automatically introduce some "jitter" in the points to remove overlap and to reorient markers (say possibly based on an description such as "Rear-End South Leg")?

I'm also curious if there are better means of creating this type of drawing then Civil3D. I'm open to any suggestions.